# Openining PopOver control and show a div with larger width

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I've inherited an existing Angular application that uses Ionic Framework (in the past it was used for web and mobile, so that's why they choose to use Ionic Framework), btw now I need to extend the version that's used in the web version and using the popover what happens is that I'm unable to show it with a larger width than the space occupied from where it's opened.

You can see what happens in the this image

[image]

What I need to achieve is something like this mockup, as you can see it has a "div" that extends on the right, and what I need is to show the date picker side by side (If I'll be able to take space I need)

[image]

Here's the code, starting from the main page

```
<ion-grid>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size=2>
        <button (click)="onDetailPageOpen();" class="scheduleButton">
            Schedule<mat-icon>list</mat-icon></button>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size=2>
        <button expand="full" (click)="presentPopover($event)" class="advancedSearchButton">
            Advanced Search<mat-icon>tune</mat-icon>
        </button >
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size=4>
        <input type="text" class="searchHere" placeholder="Search here" [(ngModel)]="SearchService.SearchText" />
      
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col size=1 style="padding-left: 135px;">
        <button  routerLink="#" class="searchButton">
            <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-col>
    
    <ion-col size=>
        
    </ion-col>

</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Then the presentPopover method

```
async presentPopover(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      componentProps: {},
      event: ev,
      
      // translucent: true
    });
    await popover.present();
  }
```

and finally the PopOverControl with the buttons

```
<ion-grid class="ionGrid">
   <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="2">
            <ion-button (click)="dateFilterPopover($event)">
                <span class="material-icons icon">
                    <span class="material-icons-outlined">
                        date_range
                    </span>
                </span>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="2"></ion-col>
        <ion-col size="2">
            <ion-button (click)="userSortPopover($event)">
                <span class="material-icons icon">
                    person
                </span>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="2"></ion-col>
        <ion-col size="2">
            <ion-button>
                <span class="material-icons iconRef">
                    refresh
                </span>
            </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row> 
</ion-grid>
```

Then the dateFilterPopOver

```
async dateFilterPopover(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverDateComponent,
      componentProps: {},
      event: ev,
      
      translucent: true
    });
    await popover.present();
  }
```

and the 2 datepicker at the end

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date From</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime 
              pickerFormat="MMM YYYY" 
              displayFormat="MMM YYYY"
              [(ngModel)]="searchService.SearchDateFrom">
</ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date To</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime 
              pickerFormat="MMM YYYY" 
              displayFormat="MMM YYYY"
              [(ngModel)]="searchService.SearchDateTo">
</ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `cssClass` with style `{max-width: 100%}` while opening `PopoverComponent` popover.

Comment: ok I give a try tomorrow and let you know, thanks

Comment: Hello, I'vetried adding ``` async dateFilterPopover(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverDateComponent,
      componentProps: {class:"cssClass"},
      event: ev,
      
      translucent: true
    });
    await popover.present();
  }
``` but it doesn't enlarge the width

Comment: can you make stackblitz with your issue.

Comment: What I meant is in .ts -> `componentProps: {cssClass: "m-w-100"}` and in .css -> `.m-w-100 { max-width: 100% }`.

Comment: I try had a bed Covid infection and being in bed till today... sorry If I was unable to answer before